# crystal report fomula to remove ampersand at the beginning or end of the string

Tags: crystal-reports, report

Need a crystal formula that would remove ampersand if any at the begging and end of a string. But not do anything if there are no ampersands at the begging or end of the string. There will be ampersands in the middle but want those to be displayed on the report. Thanks

The string would look something like this &Sample1&Sample2&Sample3& I need to change it to show Sample1&Sample2&Sample3

Comment: Please post the code you have so far and explain what the issues you are having with it.

Comment: The string would look something like this &sample1&Sample2&Sample3& I need to change it to show Sample1&Sample2&Sample3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a formula and write this inside:

```
    if left({your field}, 1) = "&" then right({your field}, len({your field})-1) 
else {your field}
```

then create another formula like:

```
    if right({your 1st formula}, 1) = "&" then left({your 1st formula}, len({your 1st formula})-1) 
else {your field}.
```

place 1st formula suppressed in a section above than the 2nd one will be displayed.